# Problems resizing a PhotoImage on RPi

Tags: tkinter, resize, python-imaging-library, tkinter-photoimage

I'm hoping someone can help with this. I've got a new install of Pi OS (1/12/23) running on an RPi 3. Searching the web, I've found that this is not a new problem but I can't seem to find the answer. My problem is that the following short code runs fine as is.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=500, height=300, bg="blue")
canvas.pack(pady=20)
im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/Downloads/Picture.png"))
#im1 = im1.resize((25,25), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img1=canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=im1)
root.mainloop()
```

It creates that blue canvas and loads Picture.png just fine.  When I remove the comment from the line to resize the image, the blue canvas loads without the Picture.png and I get the error:

```
im1 = im1.resize((25,25), Image.ANTIALIAS)
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'
```

I've done all kinds of searches on this and the code I posted is what is recommended when there are obvious errors in the original posted code. For posts that I've seen that use code like this, I've never seen a solution posted but most of them are a few years old so I'll ask. Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?????

Comment: You need to call `resize()` on the result of `Image.open(...)`.

Comment: Change this #im1 = im1.resize((25,25), Image.ANTIALIAS) to im1=im1.resizeImage((25,25))

Answer (score 0):

As the error said `resize()` is not defined inside class `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.  It is defined in class `Image` so it should be called on the result of `Image.open(...)`:

```py
im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/home/pi/Downloads/Picture.png").resize((25,25)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  I tried both of the suggestions.  Changing "resize" to "resizeImage" did not work.  I got the same error as before.  The suggeston from acw1668 to be called as part of "Image.open" did work.